# How to use timepicker widget to show start and end time using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, timepicker

I am creating a page to show start time and end time but when I couldn't find a way to update the time in individual fields. I am only using a single function to build a timepicker and showing the time.

**Here is my timepicker function**

```
Future<Null> selectedTime(BuildContext context, bool ifPickedTime) async{
_pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: _currentTime);
if (_pickedTime != null){
  setState(() {
    _currentTime = _pickedTime;
    print("The picked time is: $_pickedTime");
  });
 }
}
```

**This is my Widget Builder**

```
Widget _buildTimePick(String title, bool ifPickedTime){
return Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 80,
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: AppStyles.textTitle,
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: MyColors.borderColor),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Text(
          "${_currentTime.format(context)}",
          style: AppStyles.textBody,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          selectedTime(context, ifPickedTime);
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

[image: Here is the output]

Comment: Try using  `TextEditingController` to save and show the picked date on the TextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the question, I feel that what you want to achieve is that you want to update the start and the end time individually. But according to the code only one time is updated which is shared by both start the end time widget, so it shows the same time.

What you can do is create 2 variables one for start time and one for end time.

```
TimeOfDay _startTime;
TimeOfDay _endTime;
```

Then make your _buildTimePick function a little more flexible by passing the time to display.

```
Widget _buildTimePick(String title, bool ifPickedTime, TimeOfDay currentTime, Function(TimeOfDay) onTimePicked){
return Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 80,
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: AppStyles.textTitle,
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: MyColors.borderColor),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Text(
          currentTime.format(context),
          style: AppStyles.textBody,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          selectedTime(context, ifPickedTime,currentTime, onTimePicked);
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

Also the selectedTime function should be more flexible such that it can be used
for selecting both start and end time by creating a callback.

```
Future selectedTime(BuildContext context, bool ifPickedTime, TimeOfDay initialTime, Function(TimeOfDay) onTimePicked) async{
var _pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: initialTime);
if (_pickedTime != null){
  onTimePicked(_pickedTime);
 }
}
```

So, the final code might look something like :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MainApp());

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Home(),
    ));
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TimeOfDay startTime = TimeOfDay.now();
  TimeOfDay endTime = TimeOfDay.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        _buildTimePick("Start", true, startTime, (x) {
          setState(() {
            startTime = x;
            print("The picked time is: $x");
          });
        }),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        _buildTimePick("End", true, endTime, (x) {
          setState(() {
            endTime = x;
            print("The picked time is: $x");
          });
        }),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future selectedTime(BuildContext context, bool ifPickedTime,
      TimeOfDay initialTime, Function(TimeOfDay) onTimePicked) async {
    var _pickedTime =
        await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: initialTime);
    if (_pickedTime != null) {
      onTimePicked(_pickedTime);
    }
  }

  Widget _buildTimePick(String title, bool ifPickedTime, TimeOfDay currentTime,
      Function(TimeOfDay) onTimePicked) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 80,
          child: Text(
            title,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Text(
              currentTime.format(context),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              selectedTime(context, ifPickedTime, currentTime, onTimePicked);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: one more question the widgets are on the Modal view and the state is not updating how to solve that issue.

Comment: Its easy. Separate the widgets inside the Modal View into its own statefulwidget and then change the state of the statefulwidget. If you use state state of the parent of Modal view.. the state change will not effect inside modal view.. so all the logic of start and end time should go inside of another statefulwidget.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the TextField using TextEditingController. Put in in the `setState` so it can update the TextField whenever you pick a date.
Exp:

```
final txtController = TextEditingController();    
final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
            firstDate: DateTime(2000),
            lastDate: DateTime(2025));
        if(picked != null && picked != now) {
          setState(() {
            txtController.text = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(picked); //I'm using intl package, you can use toString()
          });
        }
```

Comment: It's ok for date picker, but how can you limit chooses in time picker?